# What's the difference between `flush` and `sync_all`?

Tags: rust

I'm curious whether I should use [`Write::flush`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) or [`File::sync_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_all) when I finish writing a file.

Comment: If you're not sure what `sync_all()` does, you should almost certainly *not* call it, it will just slow down your program without a benefit. (Its use case is in implementing software with precise data durability guarantees, such as journaled databases.) You need to `flush()` at the end of writing if you've placed a buffered writer over your actual writer. Bufwriters will typically `flush()` at drop, but that doesn't allow you to report the error, so it's better to `flush()` explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: If you want to "ensure" that the data has been written to the device, then use `File::sync_all` if you use a `File`. Note that this isn't necessary though.

---

The `Write::flush` implementation for `File` uses the operating system dependent `flush` operation, for example [`std::sys::unix::File::flush`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3802025f400af7817ba4874587e6a2df95abd65d/library/std/src/sys/unix/fs.rs#L884-L886), or [`std::sys::windows::File::flush`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3802025f400af7817ba4874587e6a2df95abd65d/library/std/src/sys/windows/fs.rs#L440-L442). Those `flush` operations do... nothing. Both implementations just return `Ok(())`.

Why? Because the `write()` already uses the underlying system call for `write()` in both cases; the handle-based write on Windows, and the file descriptor-based write on Unix-like systems. At that point, it's out of reach of the Rust environment, save for a system call that's *specific to files*.

So what ***is*** `Write::flush` useful for? It's useful if you have any kind of buffer *before* the actual file, for example a [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html). If you have a `File` wrapped by a `BufWriter`, then you need to use `flush` to ensure that the bytes get written to the file. While it's useful to keep in mind that `BufWriter`'s `Drop` implementation also tries(!) to write those bytes, it may or may not work, so you're supposed to call `Write::flush` there (see `BufWriter`'s documentation).

That being said, `sync_all` isn't necessary and instead will block your program. The operating system will handle the file system synchronisation. While you can certainly wait for that synchronisation to happen via `sync_data` or `sync_all`, you're usually better of with not doing either.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it bears pointing out that if the OP doesn't know what `sync_all()` does, they almost surely *don't* want to call it after writing out a random file. `sync_all()` doesn't really ensure that the file has been written out to the underlying hardware (the OS does that anyway), it just makes your program _wait_ until that has happened. This is only ever needed in very specialized circumstances.

Comment: @user4815162342 Good point, that's why I used the quotes about "ensure" but completely forgot to add it to the complete picture.

Comment: I had in fact noticed and appreciated the quotes about "ensure", I just felt that it might still have been too subtle for the OP (and others harboring the same confusion). Thanks for the update to the answer!

Comment: @user4815162342 No worries, you were completely right to add the comment, thanks for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 4):

`Write::flush` for on-disk file is actually a no-op [[source]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sys/unix/fs.rs.html#884-886). It's useless for `File`, just impl for consistency. This interface is meant for stream that utilizes **app-level** in-memory buffer before writing into destination, as stated in the doc:

> Flush this output stream, ensuring that all **intermediately buffered** contents reach their destination.

[`File::sync_data`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_data) is the kinda like the useful version of `flush` for `File`. Under the hood, intermediate buffer is used on kernel-level, and `sync_data` delegates to `fdatasync` POSIX call, which does what `flush` does on app-level, .

[`File::sync_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_all) does what `File::sync_data` does, and on top of that, it also ensure metadata about a file is written to disk. It delegates to `fsync` on POSIX system.

Sidenote: depending on system (e.g. macOS, android, etc.), implementation for `File::sync_data` and `File::sync_all` could be exactly the same.